# How do I populate a listbox in excel with a matrix?

Tags: excel, vba, matrix, listbox

I'm trying to populate a listbox in excel with information that is a "matrix"(basically I have some data in the rows and some in the columns. I'm using the code below but I have 2 problems.

```
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim Kolumns As Integer
Dim Start As Range

Set Start = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2")
Start.Select

Rows = 10
Kolumns = 5

For i = 1 To Rows
    For j = 1 To Kolumns
    
    ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(i - 1, j - 1) = ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value
    
    Next j
Next i
```

The first problem is that the rows is being doubled, if I write "rows = 10" I then get 20 rows. (The columns work fine).

The second problem is my "select". I know that it's not the best option to use but I don't know how to avoid it?

Comment: You can modify `ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value` as `Start.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value` and then drop `select` statement altogether.

Comment: Perfect, that works like a charm. that solves problem 2, still have the problem of the rows doubling. 
If I change "Rows = 10" to "Rows = 1" I will get 2 rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written in the comment, you can use the range variable (in your case `Start`) directly to access the content of the cells.

The reason that you get 20 instead of 10 entries in the listbox is that you have the `AddItem` within the inner loop, and that is executed 10*2 = 20 times. You need to move it into the outer loop so that only one item per row is created:

```
Const rowCount = 10
Const colCount = 2

Dim Start As Range
Set Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2")

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 1 To rowCount
    ListBox1.AddItem
    For j = 1 To colCount
        ListBox1.List(i - 1, j - 1) = Start.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the next way, please. No need of any iteration. A `ListBox` has a `List` property which accept an array:

```
Sub loadListBox()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, iRows As Long, Kolumns As Long, Start As Range, arr
 
 Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

 Set Start = sh.Range("B2")
 iRows = 10:  Kolumns = 5

 arr = sh.Range(Start, Start.Offset(iRows, Kolumns)).Value

 With ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = Kolumns + 1
    .list = arr
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Populate List Box

- More efficient is not using a loop at all.
- Note the use of the `ColumnCount` property which is used to ensure the right number of columns.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub populateListBox()
    
    Const rCount As Long = 10
    Const cCount  As Long = 5
    
    Dim cel As Range: Set cel = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    
    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = cCount
        .List = cel.Resize(rCount, cCount).Value
    End With

End Sub
```